# How can a simple closed curve not look locally like the rotated graph of a continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, plane-curves

A simple closed curve is a continuous closed curve without self-intersections.  The question of whether you can inscribe a square in every simple closed curve is currently an open problem, but [this page](http://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/%7Emarkn/squares/) describes an important partial result:

> Stromquist's Theorem: If the simple closed curve J is "nice enough" then it has an inscribed square....
>
> Here, "nice enough" means the following: for each point P on the curve there must be a coordinate system for the plane in which some piece of the curve containing P is the graph y = f(x) of a continuous function.

My question isn't about Stromquist's theorem itself, but about the condition that's dubbed  "nice enough".  It's mind-boggling that there could be a simple closed curve curve that fails to meet this condition.

I can understand continuous curves that fail the vertical line test, because two distant points on the curve have the same x-value, and I can understand situations where the vertical line test fails locally in the part of a curve containing P, because the points in that part of the curve are clustered around a vertical line.  But it's completely counterintuitive to me that you could have a point P on a simple closed curve such that no arc of the curve in the vicinity of P, no matter how small, can pass the vertical line test no matter how you rotate the arc.

So is there a simple example of such a curve?  Preferably I'd want an example where the interior of the simple closed curve was a convex region, because that's the case that my intuition most strenuously objects to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

EDIT: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem#Locally_monotone_curves) tells me that the property I've been calling "nice enough" is actually known as "locally monotone".

Comment: Do you know about Koch snowflake? It will have such property (not nice anywhere).

Comment: If the interior is convex, the curve is "nice enough".

Comment: @DanielFischer How would you prove that?

Comment: @studiosus That's not immediately obvious to me.  Wouldn't the top of the Koch Snowflake, for instance, pass the vertical line test in its local vicinity?

Comment: If you want a simpler example where one point is not nice, take a double spiral. The origin will be the bad point.

Comment: @studious What double spiral are you referring to?  I'd prefer a an example with simple closed curve if possible.

Comment: "Nice enough" basically means "not fractal in nature". If the curve is fractal-like, then it is not obvious that there is any interior big enough to contain a square..

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Assuming the curve describes a convex region: pick a ball $B(O,r)$ on the interior of the curve. (If it has no interior then it is a line segment or point.) Take the line from $O$ to $P$ as the vertical, with $P$ on the positive $y$ axis. Then for $x\in(-r,r)$, the piece of the curve above the $x$-axis will pass the vertical line test.

Comment: @Arthur What do you mean "that there is any interior"?  Doesn't the Jordan curve theorem ensure an interior?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Why would the piece of the curve above the interval $(-r,r)$ pass the vertical line test?

Comment: @Arthur I don't think the question is whether you can fit a square *inside* the region swept out by the curve; as Keshav says the Jordan Curve theorem ensures that there is an interior. The question is whether there are four points on the curve that are in a square vertex formation.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, Mario is right, the inscribed squares problem is about drawing a square using points on the curve, not drawing a square inside the interior.

Comment: @Keshav For each $x\in(-r,r)$, $(0,x)$ is in the interior; since the curve is bounded there is some $y>0$ such that $(y,x)$ is in the exterior. Let $f(x)$ be the supremum of the points in the interior closure. Then $(x,f(x))$ is on the curve and $(y,x)$ for all $0\le y<f(x)$ are in the interior closure, so the curve passes back over the line anywhere lower, unless it touches and turns around; but this possibility is excluded by considering the line segment $\overline{(x,f(x)),(x\pm\epsilon,0)}$, for $\epsilon$ small enough to still be in $(-r,r)$.

Comment: I think that most simple closed curves are not "nice enough", and that even fractal curves are special cases with defined dimension (even defined local dimension is special).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro What do you mean by "the interior closure"?  Do you mean the closure of the interior of something?  If so, what are we taking the closure of the interior of?

Comment: @Keshav I neglected to use symbols, so the names got weird. Jordan curve says that my curve $\gamma$ has a bounded interior $S$ and an exterior $\Bbb R^2\setminus\bar S$. The "interior" I refer to is $S$, and the interior closure is $\bar S$. The boundary $\partial S$ is equal to the image of $\gamma$.

Comment: Also, for the "double spiral" counterexample given, see [the parameterization](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+%28x+cos%28%28pi+x%29%2f2%2b5+log%28abs%28x%29%29%29%2c+x+sin%28%28pi+x%29%2f2%2b5+log%28abs%28x%29%29%29%29+for+x+%3d+-1+to+1) $(x\cos\theta,x\sin\theta),\theta=5\log|x|+\pi x/2$, for $x\in[-1,1]$, which is a simple closed curve that has a "funky point" at $x=0$.

Comment: The Koch snowflake does not pass the vertical line test on any neighborhood of any point on the perimeter, because there are line segments with outward normals in all six directions in the approximations in every neighborhood (so that regardless of which direction you choose to be "up", there will always be an "upside-down" line with the interior piece above the exterior piece, thereby failing the v.line test).

Comment: @MichaelCarneiro Now that I know what you mean by interior closure, I'm confused about your definition of $f(x)$.  The interior closure is a two-dimensional set of points, so what do you mean by the supremum?  Do you mean the supremum of the y-coordinates of points in the interior closure whose x-coordinate is $x$?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I put my thoughts from this thread into an answer, and hopefully clarified your questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is mostly a summary of my comments above.

A graph of a (continuous) function has the property that it only has one $y$ value for each $x$, more geometrically stated in terms of the vertical line test: Any vertical line will intersect the function at most once. A curve of a rotated function will thus pass the "vertical line test" where the lines are angled with the function, and this characterizes curves that are locally rotated function-like. An algebraic way of putting it is that there is some vector $v$ such that $\gamma(t)\cdot v$ is strictly monotonic.

It is not hard to come up with counterexamples:

- [The double spiral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric%20plot%20%28x%20cos%28%28pi%20x%29/2%2b5%20log%28abs%28x%29%29%29,%20x%20sin%28%28pi%20x%29/2%2b5%20log%28abs%28x%29%29%29%29%20for%20x%20=%20-1%20to%201) is such that every line through the origin intersects the curve infinitely many times (even when restricted to neighborhoods of $0$), so it must fail the vertical line test.
- [This curve](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric%20plot%20x-x%5E3%2bx%20sin%2810%20log%28abs%28x%29%29%2b1/2%20pi%20sgn%28x%29%29,%20abs%28x%29%20for%20x%20=%20-1%20to%201) violates the test in a somewhat different manner. Any line with slope greater than $\frac12$ through the origin intersects the curve infinitely often, but those with slope less than $\frac12$ intersect the curve once. Nevertheless, it still fails the test in neighborhoods of the origin because if the line is shifted just above the origin, it will always intersect the curve at least twice.
- [The Koch snowflake](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=koch%20snowflake%205%20iterations) is a fractal that fails the vertical line test at every point. To see this: Any neighborhood $U$ of a point on the final fractal will contain an entire line segment $\ell$ from one of the approximations (choose one such that the circle with $\ell$ as its diameter is also contained in $U$). All subsequent "refinements" of this line segment are contained in a triangle with base $\ell$ and height $\frac1{2\sqrt3}|\ell|$ (this can also be thought of as the convex hull of the first refinement of $\ell$), which are thus all in $U$. The first refinement contains a "peak" formed by two lines pointing in the same direction as the outward normal of $\ell$; subsequent refinements contain rotated peaks so that all six possible directions are represented among the refinements to $\ell$. Given any "up direction" $v$, there is a "peak" such that one line has $n_1\cdot v>0$ and the other has $n_2\cdot v<0$; a line passing through this peak is a failure of the test.

However, if the curve is known to enclose a convex region, then it will pass the test at each of its points. Suppose that the curve $\gamma$ encloses a bounded region $S$ ($S$ is taken to be open, i.e. the interior), where $\partial S=\operatorname{ran}\gamma$, and such that $S$ is convex. Given a point $P$ on the curve, pick a point $O\in S$, and set up the coordinate system such that $O$ is the origin and $P$ is on the positive $y$-axis. Since $O\in S$ and $S$ is open, there is some $r$ such that $B(O,r)\subseteq S$. Thus the points $(x,0)$ for $x\in(-r,r)$ are all in $S$. Since $S$ is bounded, for each $x$ the set $\{y:(x,y)\in\bar S\}$ is upper bounded; let $f(x)$ be the supremum of this set. Then $(x,f(x))\in\bar S$ because $\bar S$ is closed, and $(x,f(x)+\varepsilon)\notin S$ implies $(x,f(x))\in\partial S$, so $(x,f(x))$ is on the curve.

Now suppose that $(x,y)\in\partial S$ for some $y\in(0,f(x))$. Then there are arbitrarily small $\delta_1,\delta_2$ such that $(x+\delta_1,y+\delta_2)\notin\bar S$. Choose one small enough that $y+\delta_2\in(0,f(x))$ and the line through $(x,f(x))$ and $(x+\delta_1,y+\delta_2)$ crosses the $x$-axis at some $x+\varepsilon\in(-r,r)$. Now we have a contradiction, because the line $(x,f(x))\to(x+\delta_1,y+\delta_2)\to(x+\varepsilon,0)$ has $(x,f(x))\in\bar S$, $(x+\delta_1,y+\delta_2)\notin\bar S$, and $(x+\varepsilon,0)\in\bar S$, yet $\bar S$ is convex (since $S$ is). Thus there are no other points such that $(x,y)\in\partial S$, so $\gamma$ restricted to the region $(-r,r)\times[0,\infty)$ is a neighborhood of $P$ that is locally the graph of a (continuous) function.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration of your proof.  By the way, in your discussion of the examples, I hope you're keeping in mind the distinction between a neighborhood of a point in the sense of a two-dimensional open ball and neighborhood in the sense of an arc of a curve.  The vertical line test does not need to be passed for an entire open ball surrounding a point, just an arc of the curve containing the point.

Comment: @Keshav You've caught me here; I was in fact thinking in terms of a 2D neighborhood of the point. Luckily, it is the same. Obviously, if there is a 2D neighborhood of $P=\gamma(t)$ on which $\gamma$ is function-like, then since $\gamma$ is continuous this contains a 1D neighborhood of $t$. Conversely, if $\gamma[t-\delta,t+\delta]$ is function-like, then since this is a closed set and $\gamma$ is injective I can expand it vertically a bit without any extra intersections with $\gamma$: the set $\{(x,f(x)+y):|y|<\varepsilon\wedge |x-t|<\delta\}$ is a neighborhood of $P=(t,f(t))$.

Comment: I don't see how the fact that $\gamma[t-\delta,t+\delta]$ is closed and $\gamma$ is injective implies that the 2D neighborhood you specified passes the vertical line test.

Comment: @Keshav Let me modify that constuction a bit. The image of the curve in the region $[t-\delta/2,t+\delta/2]$ and $(-\infty,t-\delta]\cup[t+\delta,\infty)$ constitute two disjoint closed subsets of $\Bbb R^2$, and so they are separated by a nonzero distance $\varepsilon$; then the set of points within $\varepsilon$ of $\gamma[t-\delta/2,t+\delta/2]$ is a neighborhood of $P$ that only contains $\gamma(t-\delta,t+\delta)$.

Comment: Is there some theorem that disjoint closed sets have to be separated by some nonzero distance?

Comment: @Keshav, this is an elementary property of any compact metric space.