# Is a smooth curve locally a graph?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, analysis

Let me first introduce a defitinition.

> **Definition** (*Smooth Curve*) Let $\gamma\colon  [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ a curve (continous function). We call $\gamma$ a $C^k$-smooth curve if $\gamma'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ and if it is of class $C^k$.

So if $\gamma$ is $C^k$-smooth with $k > 0$, using this definition, does there exist for each point $v \in \gamma$ on the curve a coordinate system for the plane in which some piece of the curve containing $v$ is the graph $y = f(x)$ of a continuous function? If yes, what should a lowest $k$ can be? I'm guessing $k=1$.

I've tried thinking/finding some counter-examples, but all the counter-examples I find aren't smooth (see [*simple closed curves*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763451/how-can-a-simple-closed-curve-not-look-locally-like-the-rotated-graph-of-a-conti), this post asks the same question but for simple closed curves). Also what is interesting about the post, was a comment by Daniel Fischer. He claimed that any simple closed curve with a convex interior is also locally a graph.

If there is not true, what extra conditions should I add for it be true?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn’t the Implicit Function Theorem answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does, no wonder it felt like I have seen this theorem before. Thanks! Should I delete this post? @LeoBianco

Comment: Suppose you could parametrize your curve as $f(x,y) = 0$. It could be very difficult (or impossible) to do this explicitly, but once you assume you have this form, the affirmation is true whenever $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \neq 0$.

Comment: or I can post it as an answer. :)

Comment: Hahaha, feel free to do so. I'll immediatly upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you could parametrize your curve as $f(x,y)=0$. This could be very difficult to achieve explicitly, but once done, by the Implicit Function Theorem the assertion is valid for every point where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \neq 0$.

Comment: What if we use the following construction: taking advantage that the curve is on $\mathbb{R}^2$, see it as the xy plane of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then, choose a point (x,y,1), with (x,y,0) inside the curve, and construct a surface by linking (x,y,1) to the points of the curve with a line. Then define f(x,y) as the height of this solid with respect to the xy plane, and limit its domain to an open set containing the curve, but not (x,y,0), so f is differentiable. Aren’t the conclusions valid then?

Comment: How do you know that there is a sufficently nice $f$ with this property? Never mind finding it _explicitly_; you'll need to prove it _is there_.

Comment: Using Jordan’s theorem to assure that such an interior of the curve exists.

Comment: And it seems easy to construct the necessary isomorphisms to back everything up to $\mathbb{R}^2$, without making reference to 3-dimensional euclidian space.

Comment: A Jordan curve is not necessarily locally a graph, though. Not even if it is $C^\infty$. You need the assumption that $\gamma'(t) \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your curve has no self-intersection; otherwise it clearly won't look like like a graph near such an intersection (except it if it a closed cycle, which is also uninteresting).

For $v=\gamma(t_0)$, an appropriate rotation of your coordinate system will make $\gamma'(t_0)=(a,0)$ for some $a>0$.

However, then $\gamma_x$, the $x$-coordinate of $\gamma$, is a $\mathcal C^1$ function with positive derivative at $t_0$. So $\gamma_x$ has positive derivative in a *neighborhood* of $t_0$, and will therefore be strictly increasing in this neighborhood; and a strictly increasing continuous function has an inverse.

In this neighborhood, therefore, it is the graph of the function $x\mapsto \gamma_y(\gamma_x^{-1}(x))$.