# Covering curves with graphs of functions

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, curves, parametrization

I have just start studying about differential geometry and, after reading some basic theory about curves, the following question has arisen :

Let $\alpha:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ an injective  differentiable map such that $M\geq|\alpha'(s)|\neq0 \;\forall s \in [a,b]$ for some $M>0$. Is it true that for every $p\in C=\alpha([a,b])$ there exists $U_p$ an open neighbourhood of $p$ in $C$ (with the usual restricted topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$) and $\varphi_p:]a_p,b_p[\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $U_p=\{(s,\varphi_p(s):s\in]a_p,b_p[\}$?

Apparently, as we can see in [Is a smooth curve locally a graph?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2810828/is-a-smooth-curve-locally-a-graph) the answer is postive but, could we cover the curve with finite many $\varphi_p$?

Comment: $[a,b]$ is compact, so yes, we can

Comment: Sorry  I dont'see why, could you be more explicit?

Comment: any continuous image of a compact is compact, and any open cover of a compact has a finite subcover, so you can obtain a cover, taking $U_p$ for each $p$ on the curve, and this cover will have a finite subcover.

Comment: What does $M\geq\alpha'(s)$ mean? $\alpha'$ is a vector.

Comment: Sorry, @ArcticChar I forgot the modulus. I edit it right now, thanks.

Comment: @TimurBakiev Ok thanks. I see what you mean. And a last question: Could we reduce it to only the graph of one function?

Comment: @prosep in general I think no, and a circle is an example.

Comment: @TimurBakiev I was reviewing what you tell me yesterday , and now I am not sure about the finite covering: $U_p$ are closed sets, so  we have a covering with closed sets not with open sets? Is still being true your argument? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @prosep I’m sure those closed sets have non-empty interior

Comment: @TimurBakiev Doesn't the graph of a continuous functions  have empty interior as $\mathbb{R}^2$ subset?

Comment: @prosep you should consider the graph as a manifold itself

Comment: In other words, you can work with the preimage of $p$ instead of $p$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126916/discussion-between-prosep-and-timur-bakiev).

Answer (score 0):

For any $p$ on the curve you can consider $U_p \subset C$. $U_p$ is an open neighbourhood of $p$ in the restriction topology. Obviously, $\bigcup_{p\in C} U_p = C$, so $\{U_p\}_{p \in C}$ is an open cover of $C$. $C$ is compact as a continuous image of $[a,b]$. Hence there exists a finite subcover $\{U_{p_1}, \dots, U_{p_n}\}$.

If you still have any questions, I will be happy to answer them.

Comment: I am not sure that such $U_p$ exist. Which is the $U_p$ for $p=\alpha(0)$? It seems to me that we could ensure the existence of that $U_p$ if $\alpha$ were defined in an open interval and in that case we couldn't deduce the finitude of the family of $\varphi$. Concretely the question is how we can write locally the curve as the graph of a function in the case in  that it is defined in [a,b]  not in ]a,b[? Is tha possible?

Comment: @prosep that’s a good question, and I’m not sure, but for an interior point of $C$ it exists as was discussed in the link. In some sense, it should exist for boundary points of $C$ too. It is possible to extend our curve beyond those point smoothly, i.e. the extension will be differentiable. So the boundary point becomes interior, we apply the statement, and then we restrict what we get to $C$.

Comment: It is a good idea but why can we do that extension? Is we could do it , we also need that the derivative is nonzero in a neigborhood of $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma(1)$ in the extension and the finitude is not guarantee

Comment: @prosep in your question those conditions are satisfied I think.